# Need to fetch values from Angular JS array

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I am using a MVC model in PHP. I am getting the following string from the View layer (This is a angular.js array but I am getting it as a string):

```
[
    {
        "name" : "item",
        "price" : "123",
        "quantity" : 12,
        "id" : 1
    }, {
        "name" : "hhh",
        "price" : "000",
        "quantity" : 12,
        "id" : 2
    }, {
        "name" : "kk",
        "price" : "88",
        "quantity" : 12,
        "id" : 3
    }
]
```

How can I extract the values of name, price, quantity and id from this string and put that into insert query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is known as a **serialized array**, meaning that it is a JavaScript array in string form (JSON). You can use PHP's `json_decode` function to deserialize the string, from there you can use it as a normal array:

```
$json='[
    {
        "name" : "item",
        "price" : "123",
        "quantity" : 12,
        "id" : 1
    }, {
        "name" : "hhh",
        "price" : "000",
        "quantity" : 12,
        "id" : 2
    }, {
        "name" : "kk",
        "price" : "88",
        "quantity" : 12,
        "id" : 3
    }
]';

$array=json_decode($json);

foreach ($array as &$value) {
    var_export($value->name);
    var_export($value->price);
    var_export($value->quantity);
    var_export($value->id);
}
```

The above should display all the values in your array. I'm not sure what you mean by "put that into the insert query", but hopefully the above will help you get access to this data.